# How can I give an alias to a type in coq

Tags: alias, typedef, coq

Let's say I want to create a matrix of natural numbers in coq.

I have the built-in coq List, and to create a list of natural numbers, I just write `list nat`.

In order to create a 2-dimension list (i.e. a matrix), I need to write `list (list nat)`.

My question is: instead of writing `list (list nat)`, what should I do for coq to understand the word `matrix` exactly as if it was `list (list nat)`?

---

I tried `Notation "matrix" := list (list nat)`, `Notation "(matrix nat)" := (list (list nat))`, etc., but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just write a definition: `Definition matrix := list (list nat)`. The definition should just work for the most part (eg, you can still write `Definition foo : matrix := [nil]`, with ListNotations).

If you don't want a definition (especially because in proofs you may have to explicitly unfold the definition for some tactics), then you can use a notation. The correct syntax for that is `Notation matrix := (list (list nat))`.